# How to get Redis to start on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis

I've added the `Redistogo` nano add-on on Heroku and I've tested it out in the console successfully. However when my app tries to connect with Redis I get the following error:

Heroku Log file:

```
2011-10-12T08:19:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379):
2011-10-12T08:19:50+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:14:in `create'
```

Why is it trying to access Redis on localhost?

My Redis.rb in the config/initializers folder has this, which is almost certainly the problem.

```
#What's pasted below is pasted ad verbatim. I don't know what to change the values to.

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

Comment: I guess ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]  is localhost? Try to using you heroku domain url for this variable in production.

Comment: Heroku set REDISTOGO_URL for you when you add the addon to be the redis to go instance URL

Comment: If it's set the URL, why would it be attempting localhost?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you using Resque?  If so, you'll need to tell Resque which Redis to use.

```
Resque.redis = REDIS
```

If not, then the code you've posted about is NOT setting your REDIS connection up.

Comment: BTW, you can add this line either at the end of the initializer file shown in the question, or you can just replace the ```REDIS``` variable with ```Resque.redis``` in the initializer for things to work.

Comment: mega thumbs up. this was the solution to my problem. its weird because i used ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] not ENV["my_actual_url_from_heroku"] and it worked in heroku

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
heroku config --long | grep REDIS
```

to see what your REDISTOGO_URL is. You might have set it accidentally.

Comment: Try letting the Redis gem deal with your URL: `Redis.connect(:url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])`

Comment: thank you. your line gave me the inspiration to...not explicitly write something in ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]