# Want to use Redis on Heroku (Redis::CannotConnectError ( Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)) )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, ruby-on-rails-4, puma

I want to use Redis on Heroku but I got this error `Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED))` .

I checked these , but didn't get helped.
[Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754304/redis-connection-to-127-0-0-16379-failed-connect-econnrefused), [deploying redis to heroku unable to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661026/deploying-redis-to-heroku-unable-to-connect), [How to get Redis to start on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737191/how-to-get-redis-to-start-on-heroku) .

I use Ruby 2.0.0p247 and Rails4. I'm using puma.

I use RedisToGo(nano) and, in /config/initializers/redis.rb I write this.

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/" )
$redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

I checked "REDISTOGO_URL" is the same URL that I can see when `$ heroku config` .

I did Redis restart on Heroku GUI, but it doesn't work.

Please tell me anything I need to do.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to connect to your own computer (note 127.0.0.1 == localhost). I'm guessing that's not the Redis server you're looking for :)

Looks like `ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]` isn't properly set.

---

Also, just a  side note, look up [Redis To Go](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo) if you haven't already, which is what most people use as a Redis server in conjunction with Heroku.

Comment: Thank you, Varatis. The bad point was I put the redis url(value) inside ENV[], not the key. That's why Redis didn't work.

Answer (score 11):

Check which **ENV** variable should contain redis configuration

For example if you are going to use Redis for Sidekiq you need to map **ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"]** to **ENV["REDIS_PROVIDER"]**
because Sidekiq is expecting to get redis configuration from **ENV["REDIS_PROVIDER"]**

You can do it this way

```
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL
```

Also you don't need to **URI.parse**, Redis will do it instead of you in case it is needed.

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL' || "redis://localhost:6379/"])
```

I suggest to use the gem [**figaro**](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to set ENV variables for your local development. Thus you remove **OR** statement

```
$redis = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])
```

and set alternative value in your **config/application.yml**

```
REDISTOGO_URL: redis://127.0.0.1:6379
```